# How to increase counter when the correct image is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick, setinterval

I have written in HTML and Javascript a webpage that cycles through an image of a lion and a frog. I have set 2 buttons to start and stop the images from cycling every 500ms. My problem is I am unsure how to go around creating a score function that counts the number of times a specific image is clicked. For example, if the frog image is clicked I want the score to +1 and if the lion image is clicked I want the score to -1.
Here is my code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Question 2</title>
      <script>
        var images = ["frog.jpg", "lion.jpg"] //I Created an array with both images inside
        var imgInterval;
        var imgi = 'empty';
        var score = document.getElementById('score');
        function start(){
          imgInterval = setInterval(displayImage, 500); //Sets an interval for the func displayImage and for it to loop ever 500ms
        }

        function displayImage() {
          if (imgi == 'empty') { //If the index is empty set the interval to 0 or frog.jpg
          imgi = 0;
        } else if (imgi == 0) { // If the index is set to 0 set it to 1 or lion.jpg
          imgi = 1;
        } else if (imgi == 1) { // If the idex is set to 1 set it back to 0, this creates a loop that will be run every 500ms
          imgi = 0;
        }
          document.getElementById('image').src = images[imgi];
        }

        function stop(){
          clearInterval(imgInterval);
        }

        function scoreNumb() { //This is where i think i am having issues and am unsure what to do.
          if (imgi.onclick == 0) {
            score + 1;
          }
        }
        </script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <button onclick=start()>Start Animation</button>
      <button onclick=stop()>Stop Animation</button>
      <br/> <br/>
      <span>
        <img id="image" onclick=scoreNumb() width="250px" />
      </span>
      <br/>
      <span id="score">0</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. You just need to check which image was `clicked` by `checking` the img `src`

If the image `src` is `lion` then you can increase the `totalScore` count variable update the `count` as well using `textContent` method.

```
function scoreNumb(e) {
  if (e.getAttribute('src') == 'https://via.placeholder.com/150') {
    totalScore++
  } else {
    totalScore--
  }
  score.textContent = totalScore
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/150", "https://via.placeholder.com/200"] //I Created an array with both images inside
var imgInterval;
var imgi = 'empty';
var score = document.getElementById('score');
var totalScore = 0

function start() {
  imgInterval = setInterval(displayImage, 1000); //Sets an interval for the func displayImage and for it to loop ever 500ms
}

function displayImage() {
  if (imgi == 'empty') { //If the index is empty set the interval to 0 or frog.jpg
    imgi = 0;
  } else if (imgi == 0) { // If the index is set to 0 set it to 1 or lion.jpg
    imgi = 1;
  } else if (imgi == 1) { // If the idex is set to 1 set it back to 0, this creates a loop that will be run every 500ms
    imgi = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('image').src = images[imgi];
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(imgInterval);
}

function scoreNumb(e) { //This is where i think i am having issues and am unsure what to do.
  if (e.getAttribute('src') == 'https://via.placeholder.com/150') {
    totalScore++
  } else {
    totalScore--
  }
  score.textContent = totalScore
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Question 2</title>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick=start()>Start Animation</button>
  <button onclick=stop()>Stop Animation</button>
  <br /> <br />
  <span>
      <img id="image" onclick=scoreNumb(this) width="250px" />
    </span>
  <br />
  <span id="score">0</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I feel like this is abit to complicated for what im asking but works nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: @TurkeyDurkey i could use the `index` of the image as well. but i felt like its ideal if you specifically want to ideatify `lion` or `frog` by its src incase you have alot of images - Glad it all working now. Let me know please if i can help any further at all mate :)

Comment: will do, ill try to keep in touch!

Answer (score 2):

replace your function scoreNumb with mine

```
  <script>
    ...
    var score = document.getElementById('score');
    var valueScore = 0; /*created this*/
    ...

    function scoreNumb() { //This is where i think i am having issues and am unsure what to do.
      /*if (imgi.onclick == 0) {
        score + 1;
      }*/
      /*0 = frog AND 1 = lion*/
      if (imgi == 0){/*+1*/
      valueScore++;
      }else {
      valueScore--;
      }
      console.log("click", valueScore);
      document.getElementById('score').textContent = valueScore;
    }
```

Comment: @zerbene yes correct. its always ideal to use `textContent` (Where there is just a text being replaced). You can read more about [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) drawbacks on MDN here in the `Security considerations` section

Answer (score 1):

Change this variable declaration from:

```
let score = document.getElementById('score');
```

to this:

```
let score = 0;
```

then in the function named scoreNumb() change the following :

```
if (imgi.onclick == 0) {
  score + 1;
}
```

to this :

```
if (imgi === 0) {
  score += 1;
}
else{
  score -= 1;
}
// Here you can update your html code with getElementById.
console.log(score)
```